# Passing parameterized function handle in Python

Tags: python, function, lambda, partial-application

I have a general function that defines a form of an ODE that I plan to integrate using [`scipy.integrate.odeint`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html), for example:

```
def my_ode(K, tau, y, u):
  return K*u/tau - y/tau  # dydt
```

I have several objects in my code that all have dynamics of the form defined in `my_ode`, but with unique parameters `K` and `tau`. I would love to be able to just pass a unique handle to `my_ode` with those parameters already set when I initialize my objects, so that when I update my objects, all I have to do is something like `soln = odeint(my_ode, t, y, u)` for some simulation time `t`.

For example, if I define a class:

```
class MyThing:
  def __init__(self, ode, y0):
    # I would rather not maintain K and tau in the objects, I just want the ODE with unique parameters here.
    self.ode = ode
    self.y = y0
    self.time = 0.0

  def update(self, t, u):
    # I want this to look something like:
    self.y = scipy.integrate.odeint(self.ode, t, self.y, u)
```

Can I do something with Lambdas when I initialize instances of `MyThing` to basically assign parameters `K` and `tau` at initialization and never need to pass them again? I am a bit stuck.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look a the [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function of `functools` module, it may be useful in your case.

Comment: Can I just initialize my object with `thing = MyThing(lambda t, y, u: my_ode(K1, tau1, t, y, u), y0)`, providing values for `K1` and `tau1` at initialization? Will these values then persist? I am not yet at a place where I can test it in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution with lambdas

It looks like I can make this work using lambdas to generate unique function handles when I initialize my objects. For compatibility with `odeint`, I need to define my functions so that the first two arguments are time and initial state:

```
def my_ode(t, y, u, K, tau):
  return K*u/tau - y/tau  # dydt
```

Next I can initialize objects of `MyThing` using lambdas to set `K` and `tau` as:

```
thing1 = MyThing(lambda t, y, u: my_ode(t, y, u, 10.0, 0.5), 0.0)
```

The function handle that gets assigned to `thing1.ode` is now the function handle returned by the lambda (this may not be the right way to say this) with values for `K` and `tau` set. Now in `thing1.update`, I need to make some changes to get it to work with `odeint`:

```
def update(self, t_step, t_end, u):
  t_array = np.arange(self.time, t_end, t_step)  # time values at which to evaluate ODE
  response = scipy.integrate.odeint(self.ode, self.y, t_array, (u,))
  self.y = response[-1]  # current state is the last evaluated state
```

One thing that tripped me up a bit is that any extra arguments to your ODE need to be passed as a tuple to `odeint`. This seems to work pretty well for what I want.

There is also the more object-oriented approach using [`scipy.integrate.ode`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html), which allows for step-wise integration of the function and is great for my simulation purposes. For this, I set the object's ODE and update it with something like:

```
class MyThing():
  def __init__(self, ode, y0):
    self.ode = integrate.ode(ode)  # define the ODE
    self.ode.set_integrator("dopri5")  # choose an integrator
    self.ode.set_initial_value(y0)

  def update(self, u, t_step):
    """Update the ODE step-wise."""
    self.ode.set_f_params(u)  # need to pass extra parameters with this method
    self.ode.integrate(self.ode.t + t_step)  # step-wise update
    return self.ode.successful()
  
  def get_output(self):
    """Get output from ODE function."""
    return self.ode.y
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have:

```
def my_ode(K, tau, y, u):
    return K*u/tau - y/tau
```

you could define something like:

```
def make_ode_helper(k, tau): 
    return lambda y, u: my_ode(K, tau, y, u)
```

and should be able to initialize MyThing with:

```
mt = new MyThing(make_ode_helper(k, tau), y0)
```

then you could call this helper with only y and u parameters:

```
someresult = ode_helper(y, u)
```

Comment: Could I then call `self.ode(y, u)` as shown in your example, since the lambda function returned by `make_ode_helper` will be assigned to this attribute of my class? I think this is what I am looking for if so!

Comment: Most probably yes, give it a try.

Comment: I tried it out, and got the error "tuple parameter unpacking is not supported in Python 3". After removing the brackets, i.e. modifying it as  `return lambda y, u: my_ode(K, tau, y, u)` it worked fine. Tested in a similar context with PyCharm (latest version) and Python 3.11